# Google script method getLastRow getting null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function getInfo(){
  var id = "xyz";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = 2; i < (lastRow + 1); i++){
  var Emails = sheet.getRange(i, getColIndexByName("Email")).getValue();

  var row = Compare(Emails, id);

  if(row)
    PlusFreq(row, id);
  else if (checkEmail(Emails))
    setEmail(Emails, id);
  }
}
```

My code is working fine , but the method getLastRow();
isn't working it's getting null, Why that is happening?

A week ago it was working properly but now does not it, besides I use the method en getLastRow other functions and also was not this working anymore.

Comment: Well clearly something in the `getLastRow()` function isn't working, can't help if we can't see it

Comment: this method is defined by google!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the error but do not know what it caused it, simply deleted the blank lines that existed after the 60 lines of content, and added them again, so stopped the error, I'm sure the lines estavao blank. error crazy

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the following line in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#getLastRow):

> method getLastRow()
>
> Returns the position of the last row that has content.

You may have to check that the sheet contains at least one row with content before you call the `getLastRow()` function.

Comment: My spreadsheet has 60 rows filled, and about 10 columns, I already used this script, but the method stopped working XS.